# How enable SSLV3 in Android 8(Oreo)?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I need to use SSLV3 on android 8. I use direct socket connection. I do not use http connection. My server only supports SSLV3 and for reasons I can not change the server side. I need a solution on the client side. Android 8 does not support ssl (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html). Could someone help me solve this problem?

```
 25766-26143/xx.com.xxx E/GeneralError: cipherSuite SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is not supported.
                                                          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cipherSuite SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is not supported.
                                                              at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.checkEnabledCipherSuites(NativeCrypto.java:968)
                                                              at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLParametersImpl.java:264)
                                                              at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:895)
                                                              at xxx.com.xxx.communication.TrustAllSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(TrustAllSSLSocketFactory.java:128)
```

Comment: SSLv3 is not secure, consider upgrading your server.

Comment: OkHttp might still support [SSLv3](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/TlsVersion.html#SSL_3_0). But, seriously, you should be talking to an attorney regarding the legal ramifications (for you personally and for your organization) for running an undeniably insecure server. If nothing else, put a reverse proxy in front of this server, one that supports modern encryption, and put your insecure server behind your firewall (reachable only by the reverse proxy).

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but I know the SSL insecurity, but what I need is to use socket connection using sslV3 protocol. For reasons I can not act on the server side. I have to act on the client side.

Comment: I need it too, server side isn't my responsible, so I have to enable SSLV3 in android.